# dotnet core 2.0 commands not running in docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up my dotnet core app to run through docker on my mac. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "backend.dll"]
```

When I run: `docker build -t backend .`

I get :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.133MB
Step 1/10 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
 ---> 76d532b4a0ca
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c04cc3784c1
Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18b53c11abd6
Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 46f3843faad7
Aborted
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 134
```

I did some debugging and noticed when I ran any command of dotnet it bombs. I ran dotnet --info and it showed the information but also Aborted. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add verbosity flag to `RUN dotnet restore --verbosity` step to see more info about the problem. Also what version of dotnet core is in your project?

Comment: I get the same output as before. I feel like it dies on the dotnet command so it doesn't even understand the flag.